# ROS hydro opencv2 linking error during 'catkin_make'

Tags: c++, opencv, ros

I have little problem with my ROS hydro distro. I need to use it for one project so can't change to Indiko.

Problem is that I have used `catkin_create_pkg packname opencv2 ...` for creating my project package. But when I try to invoke `catkin_make` I get following errors:

> CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75
>   (find_package):   Could not find a package configuration file provided
>   by "opencv2" with any   of the following names:
>
> ```
> opencv2Config.cmake
> opencv2-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "opencv2" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
>   "opencv2_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
>   "opencv2" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
>   has   been installed.

I know that opencv2 is installed, because I can find it with `rospack find opencv2` and I can use it in other projects not related to ROS.

I have following lines in CMakeLists.txt and package.xml

CMakeLists.txt:

> find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS opencv2)
>
> include_directories( 
>   ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
>   ${opencv2_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
>
> target_link_libraries(BasicObstDetect_node
>    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
>    ${opencv2_LIBRARIES}  )

package.xml:

> `<build_depend>opencv2</build_depend>`
>
> `<run_depend>opencv2</run_depend>`

I have tried to use OpenCV instead of opencv2 but that didn't make any difference. Any advices?

Comment: answers.ros.org is a better place for these questions.

Comment: Thanks! posted my question there.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure, but this might work: edit your `CMakeLists` to add

```
find_package(OpenCV)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

and
`target_link_libraries(follower ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})`