# ROS Kinetic Opencv3 Cmake error

Tags: opencv3.0, ros

I try to use opencv3 with ROS kinetic binary packages but when I use catkin_make I have an error that I can't fix !

Result of rospack find opencv3 : **/opt/ros/kinetic/share/opencv3**

**Error:** CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "opencv3" with any
  of the following names:

```
opencv3Config.cmake
opencv3-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "opencv3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "opencv3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "opencv3" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use OpenCV 3 in ROS Kinetic, you only need to do the following in your CMakeLists.txt: `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)`, because OpenCV 3 is the default in ROS Kinetic. Pay attention to the capitalization, it must be `OpenCV` (i.e. <strike>`find_package(opencv)`</strike> is not going to work!)

References: Section 1.2 and 2 at http://wiki.ros.org/opencv3

Comment: I changed my CMakeLists.txt :

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS  cv_bridge
  OpenCV
  rospy
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
)

Comment: The error is :
-- ==> add_subdirectory(vision_circle)
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.

Comment: Do not use `find_package(catkin ...` but add another statement `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)`

Answer (score 0):

I used this post for opencv2 :
[[ROS hydro opencv2 linking error during 'catkin_make'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264306/ros-hydro-opencv2-linking-error-during-catkin-make?rq=1][1])

I put in Cmake:
find_package(OpenCV)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})